# help with chained selects and existing form values, ex: adding <option selected="selected"></option>

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, select, chaining

I have a 3 step chained-select sequence, `game -> battle -> winning side` , which pulls all data from a MySQL database.

After some wandering on the internet, I found a compact jQuery script that performs wonderfully. However, I am at a loss as to how to allow for existing data: `<option selected="selected"></option>` using this script.

chained select javascript:

```
<script>
var ajax = new Array();

function getScenNumList(sel)
{
    var game = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById('scenarioNumber').options.length = 0;   // Empty scenario number select box
    if(game.length>0){
        var index = ajax.length;
        ajax[index] = new sack();

        ajax[index].requestFile = 'js/getPlayData.php?gameName='+game;  // Specifying which file to get
        ajax[index].onCompletion = function(){ createScenarioNumbers(index) };  // Specify function that will be executed after file has been found
        ajax[index].runAJAX();      // Execute AJAX function
    }
}

function createScenarioNumbers(index)
{
    var obj = document.getElementById('scenarioNumber');
    eval(ajax[index].response); // Executing the response from Ajax as Javascript code
}

function getNations(sel)
{
    var scenNum = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById('victor').options.length = 0;   // Empty nation select box
    if(scenNum.length>0){
        var index = ajax.length;
        ajax[index] = new sack();

        ajax[index].requestFile = 'js/getPlayData.php?scenID='+scenNum; // Specifying which file to get
        ajax[index].onCompletion = function(){ createNations(index) };  // Specify function that will be executed after file has been found
        ajax[index].runAJAX();      // Execute AJAX function
    }
}

function createNations(index)
{
    var obj = document.getElementById('victor');
    eval(ajax[index].response); // Executing the response from Ajax as Javascript code
}

</script>
```

excerpt from the PHP database retrieval script (`getPlayData.php`):

```
$gameName = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['gameName']);

$q = "SELECT a, b, c FROM table WHERE game='$gameName' ORDER BY num ASC";

$r = mysql_query($q);

echo "obj.options[obj.options.length] = new Option('#','');\n";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($r)) {

    $string = mysql_real_escape_string(($row[0].' - '.$row[1])); // needed so quotes ' " don't break the javascript

    echo "obj.options[obj.options.length] = new Option('$string','$row[2]');\n";

}
```

echoing the `obj.options` is the stock method this script was using. It seems ugly to me, but I don't know any javascript so I didn't want to fiddle with it.

The HTML is simple enough, just a table with a few empty `<select>` objects with IDs matching those in the javascript and `onchange="getXXX(this)"` calls.

**My question is this:** Everything works great for new records, but I'm at a loss as to how I can alter this to support marking one option from each select as selected, assuming I have that data in hand (ex: a user is editing an existing record) ?

Many thanks!

Comment: you want any option to be selected or some specific one?

Comment: @Vivik - currently I'm using this for inputing new play records, but I'd like to be able to use it for editing existing records as well. In which case, I'd have the game, battle, and winning side data in hand (from the database) and I want the form to load with these items already selected. Doing this is trivial with *just* PHP, but then I don't have a chained select function. Does that help clarify?

Comment: @Anrew: what do you mean in "but then I don't have a chained select function"? Those javascript function does not relate to how you could display existed data by PHP.

Comment: @coolkid - the javascript drives the chain ability. Without the javascript, these are just 3 independent select boxes. Using PHP, I know how to auto-generate a select box and mark any option I please as selected given an input datapoint. I don't know how to do that in the context of this javascript-driven chain select, because the `<option></option>` creation method is completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this tutorial for creating an option that is selected as default. http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/selectcontent.shtml One parameter in the option constructor dictate that whether the option is selected or not.

In the PHP file you will edit as follow:

```
$gameName = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['gameName']);

$q = "SELECT a, b, c FROM table WHERE game='$gameName' ORDER BY num ASC";

$r = mysql_query($q);

echo "obj.options[obj.options.length] = new Option('#','');\n";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($r)) {

    $string = mysql_real_escape_string(($row[0].' - '.$row[1])); // needed so quotes ' " don't break the javascript
    if ($string ......)
    echo "obj.options[obj.options.length] = new Option('$string','$row[2]', false, true);\n";
    else
     ......
```

}

Comment: Seems logical that the solution would be setting an existing parameter in the JS. I will try this out tonight and happily award you the answer if it works! :-)